# How do I split the level of a pandas.MultiIndex into two new levels?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas.MultiIndex` where i want to "split up" one of the levels in two:

For example:

```
level_1   level_2         
a1        b1/c1   
          b1/c2    
          b2/c1
```

->

```
level_1   level_2_1  level_2_2 
a1        b1         c1     
                     c2     
          b2         c1
```

what is a good, efficient way to do this?

One solution I'm aware of uses `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples`:

```py
pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
    (x, y[0], y[1])
    for x, y in zip(
        index.get_level_values("level_1"),
        index.get_level_values("level_2").map(lambda x: x.split("/")).map(tuple)
    )],
    names=["level_1", "level_2_1", "level_2_2"]
)
```

but this is super slow.

what's the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you give code to construct a full input dataframe and show your expected output dataframe?

Comment: Can you check your input value for third row 'b1/c1' should that be 'b2/c1' to match output? Or do you need some sort of incrementing logic here?

Comment: @ScottBoston thanks for asking. Sure, I'll edit to provide a fuller example. I gave an index only because sometimes I have a Series, other times a DataFrame. And my goal is just to alter the index, nothing more.

Comment: @ScottBoston re `b1/c1` - sorry, typo :) corrected as you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the array constructor or the default constructor for the `MultiIndex`. The process would work like this:

- break apart your index `'level_2'` on the `'/'`
- combine the `'level_1'` from the old index with each part of the split index.
- re-construct the `MultiIndex`

First lets construct a `Series` & `MultiIndex` to work with:

```py
import pandas as pd

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [['a1'], ['b1/c1', 'b1/c2', 'b2/c1']], names=['level_1', 'level_2']
)
s = pd.Series(0, index=index)

print(s)
level_1  level_2
a1       b1/c1      0
         b1/c2      0
         b2/c1      0
dtype: int64
```

### Default `MultiIndex` Constructor

I haven't timed this, but my guess is that this will be the most performant solution.

```py
split_idx = s.index.get_level_values('level_2').str.split('/', expand=True)

# combine old/new indexes here
codes = [s.index.codes[0], *split_idx.codes]
levels = [s.index.levels[0], *split_idx.levels]
names = [s.index.names[0], *[f'level_2_{i}' for i in range(1, split_idx.nlevels+1)]]

new_index = pd.MultiIndex(codes=codes, levels=levels, names=names)

print(new_index)
MultiIndex([('a1', 'b1', 'c1'),
            ('a1', 'b1', 'c2'),
            ('a1', 'b2', 'c1')],
           names=['level_1', 'level_2_1', 'level_2_2'])

print(s.set_axis(new_index))
level_1  level_2_1  level_2_2
a1       b1         c1           0
                    c2           0
         b2         c1           0
dtype: int64
```

### `MultiIndex.from_arrays` Constructor

This is may be a more readable solution because the `from_arrays` constructor is more familiar than the default constructor.

```py
split_idx = index.get_level_values(1).str.split('/', expand=True)

# Build new index structure, seeded with the first level of the original Index
arrays = [s.index.get_level_values(0)]
names = [s.index.names[0]]
for level in range(split_idx.nlevels):
    arrays.append(split_idx.get_level_values(level))
    names.append(f'level_2_{level+1}')

new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=names)

print(new_index)
MultiIndex([('a1', 'b1', 'c1'),
            ('a1', 'b1', 'c2'),
            ('a1', 'b2', 'c1')],
           names=['level_1', 'level_2_1', 'level_2_2'])

print(s.set_axis(new_index))
level_1  level_2_1  level_2_2
a1       b1         c1           0
                    c2           0
         b2         c1           0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: thanks! this is great. would you also recommend: (1) create a new multiindex just from `level_2`, (2) append this to the original index, (3) drop `level_2`? or maybe adding levels to a preexisting index is not performant?

Comment: `pandas` should be reconstructing these objects internally (when using `.set_index(…, append=True) and `droplevel`, so this route probably creates a temporary `MultiIndex`. Whereas the code above can avoid that. If you're looking for performance, should be a good bet. If you're looking for pure readability, a `droplevel` with a `set_index(…, append=True)` may be worth looking into

Comment: So [`set_index(…, append=True)`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.5.0/pandas/core/frame.py#L6059) uses [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/87cfe4e38bafe7300a6003a1d18bd80f3f77c763/pandas/core/indexes/base.py#L7275-L7312) under the hood- actually VERY similar to the solution I posted above. This means that the default constructor method I posted should be more performant.

Answer (score 2):

Not too sure about your exact use-case, please share more details on your input/output. I would try something like the following if the MultiIndex is on the index.

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df[["level_2_1","level_2_2"]] = df["level_2"].str.split("/",expand=True)
df.drop(["level_2"],axis=1,inplace=True)
df.set_index(["level_1","level_2_1","level_2_2"])
```

hope it helps!

Comment: thanks! upvoting as this works but i have a few concerns... i usually have a Series, so i can't use `set_index` or `drop` etc. i guess i could call `to_frame`, etc... but i'm really interested in doing this without relying on DataFrames. (seems like that is slower and has a more complicated implementation?) any implementations using just `pd.Index` API would be more desirable.